# oracle parametrizes query - how to change/remove/modify parameter

Tags: c#, oracle

here is my scenario:
I use simple c# winform to query a data from my database table - let's call it XTable.  Winform has a combo box which contain a distinct values from column ACol from XTable.  Below the code

query:

```
select * from XTable where ACO = :param
```

c#

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OracleDataReader odr;
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\query.sql");
string zap = read.ReadToEnd();
OracleCommand ocom = new OracleCommand(zap, ocn);
ocom.Parameters.Add(":param", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = this.cmbError.text;
odr = ocom.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(odr);
```

Until I choose a signle value from combo it works as I expect. But I wanted to add on the first place sign  * (star)  to my combobox values. The star means: no filter, get all values from combobox. 
How to build a sql query to meet my needs ?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SQL statement that is being executed, an example of the results that this statement returns, and an example of what you want it to return. Thanks.

Comment: I wish every asker would post a test case with any SQL or PL/SQL question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have two queries one when the value is `*` and other one when the value is different from `*`. I don't know why you are loading your query from SQL file. **This cost resources**. Better write it as string.

```
if(this.cmbError.text != "*")
    string sql = "select * from XTable where ACO = :param"
else
    string sql = "select * from XTable
```

And you should add parameter only when the value is different from "*"

```
if(this.cmbError.text != "*")
     ocom.Parameters.Add(":param", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = this.cmbError.text;
```

Also if you are using `StreamReader`, `OracleDataReader` you must dispose them!

You can do this like this:

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\query.sql"))
{

}
```

This calls `Dispose` automatically, even when an exception happens. If you don't wrap it in using block you should use try/catch/finally.

```
try
{
       StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\query.sql")
}
catch
{
       throw;
}
finally
{
    reader.Close();   // Close call dispose.
}
```

Comment: no need to shout/bold/etc. I use to dispose StreamReaders but to shorten as much as possible the code I removed it.  Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: If it was with CAPS it will be shout. Formatting the question is to show meaningful parts of the question. Most of the users here read question/answers between the line. I'm trying to point out every problem which I see. You don't show the Dispose part, because of that I wrote about it, because if you don't dispose it you will have problems. Anyway good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

Test for selected index of 0 and process like this:

```
if(this.cmbError.SelectedIndex == -1 || this.cmbError.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
  ocom.Parameters.Add(":param", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = DB.Null;
}
else
{
 ocom.Parameters.Add(":param", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = 
    cmbError.text;
}
```